# Extract text with optional group using regex with RE.VERBOSE

Tags: python, regex

I am extracting some information from HTM text with RE.VERBOSE. Because the HKDMOPrate is not always present in the code, I make it as an optional group. However, the code don't work as expected. Here is my code:

```
def get_primerate_result(text):
    pattern="""
        (effect\sfrom\s)
        (?P<Date>[A-Za-z0-9\,\s]+)
        (\s\()
        (.*USD\sprime\srate)
        (.*to\s)
        (?P<USDrate>[0-9\.\%]+)
        (\sp\.a\.)
        ((.*HKD\sand\sMOP\sprime\srate)
        (.*to\s)
        (?P<HKDMOPrate>[0-9\.\%]+)
        (\sp\.a\.))?
    """

    dict_result=[i.groupdict() for i in re.finditer(pattern, text, re.VERBOSE)]
    return dict_result
```

The following are two example input:

**Input:**

**Text 1:**

```py
'Dear Customers,\nWith the Federal Reserve System raising its federal funds rate by 0.25%, our bank is here to announce that with effect from July 28, 2023 (Friday), our USD prime rate will be increased from 8.25% p.a. to 8.50% p.a., our HKD and MOP prime rate will be increased from 6.00% p.a. to 6.125% p.a.\nBank of China Limited Macau Branch\nBank of China (Macau) Limited\nJuly 27, 2023\nPlease click to check：\n\nPrime Rate\n'
```

**Text 2:**

```py
'Dear Customers,\nWith the Federal Reserve System raising its federal funds rate by 0.25%, our bank is here to announce that with effect from March 24, 2023 (Friday), our USD prime rate will be increased from 7.75% p.a. to 8.00% p.a.\nBank of China Limited Macau Branch\nBank of China (Macau) Limited\nMarch 24, 2023\nPlease click to check\n\nPrime Rate\n'
```

**The following is my desired output:**

```py
result 1: [{'Date': 'July 28, 2023', 'USDrate': '8.50%', 'HKDMOPrate': '6.125%'}]
result 2: [{'Date': 'March 24, 2023', 'USDrate': '8.00%', 'HKDMOPrate': None}]
```

**The actual output**

```py
result 1: [{'Date': 'July 28, 2023', 'USDrate': '6.125%', 'HKDMOPrate': None}]
result 2: [{'Date': 'March 24, 2023', 'USDrate': '8.00%', 'HKDMOPrate': None}]
```

Comment: A quick fix is to make the `.*` before `to` lazy: [`(.*?to\s)`](https://regex101.com/r/zVFzXB/1).

Comment: It works! Thank you. Can you explain why? I don't get the logic behind.

Comment: `.*` is greedy, it first matches everything and then backtracks one character by one until it meets a `to`, which is the second (and *the last*) `to` in the same line. `?` makes `*` lazy, ensuring that it grasp one character by one until it meets a `to`, which is *the first* `to`. Also, just [throw all those useless groupings away](https://regex101.com/r/zVFzXB/3) if you don't need them.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As suggested by InSync, the problem is solved by making the `.*` before to lazy: `(.*?to\s)`.